# Converting Rx-Observables to Twitter Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, rx-java, rx-scala

I want to implement the following functions in the most re-active way. I need these for implementing the bijections for automatic conversion between the said types.

```
def convertScalaRXObservableToTwitterFuture[A](a: Observable[A]): TwitterFuture[A] = ???
def convertScalaRXObservableToTwitterFutureList[A](a: Observable[A]): TwitterFuture[List[A]] = ???
```

I came across [this](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/11/converting-between-completablefuture.html) article on a related subject but I can't get it working.

Comment: Which article is that?

Comment: oops. sorry. added the link now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the claim in that article is not correct and there can't be a true bijection between `Observable` and anything like `Future`. The thing is that `Observable` is more powerful abstraction that can represent things that can't be represented by `Future`. For example, `Observable` might actually represent an infinite sequence. For example see [`Observable.interval`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#interval-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). Obviously there is no way to represent something like this with a `Future`. The [`Observable.toList`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#toList--) call used in that article explicitly mentions that:

> Returns a `Single` that emits a single item, a list composed of all the items emitted by the ***finite*** source `ObservableSource`.

and later it says:

> Sources that are infinite and never complete will never emit anything through this operator and an infinite source may lead to a fatal OutOfMemoryError.

Even if you limit yourself to only finite `Observable`s, still `Future` can't fully express semantics of `Observable`. Consider [`Observable.intervalRange`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#intervalRange-long-long-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) that generates a limited range one by one over some time period. With `Observable` the first event comes after `initialDelay` and then you get event each `period`. With `Future` you can get only one event and it must be only when the sequence is fully generated so `Observable` is completed. It means that by transforming `Observable[A]` into `Future[List[A]]` you immediately break the main benefit of `Observable` - reactivity: you can't process events one by one, you have to process them all in a single bunch.

To sum up the claim at the first paragraph of the article:

> convert between the two, without loosing asynchronous and event-driven nature of them.

is false because conversion `Observable[A]` -> `Future[List[A]]` exactly looses the "event-driven nature" of `Observable` and there is no way to work this around.

P.S. Actually the fact that `Future` is less powerful than `Observable` should not be a big surprise. If it was not, why anybody would create `Observable` in the first place?